# Drop down Language selection not remembering choice

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My Language drop-down still will not keep the language I selected as default I followed the docs as is on the Microsoft asp.net core tutorials. But in the docs, it does not state how to have the dropdown remember the state.

It doesn't state in the documentation how the dropdown should remember its state the cookie gets saved and stores the name of the culture as it should as seen in the screen shot.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1

```
@{
    var cultureItems = LocOptions.Value.SupportedUICultures
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Name, Text = c.NativeName })
        .ToList();
    var returnUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.Request.Path) ? "~/" : $"~{Context.Request.Path.Value}";
}

<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="languageDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        @Localizer["Language"]
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="languageDropdown">
        @foreach (var language in @cultureItems)
        {
            <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-culture="@language.Value" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl">@language.Text</a>
        }
    </div>
</li>
```

Here is my startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {

            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddLocalization(options => { options.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; });
        services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new[] { new CultureInfo("en"), new CultureInfo("fr") };

            options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en", uiCulture: "en");
            options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            options.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
            {
                new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider(),
                new CookieRequestCultureProvider()
            };
        });


        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services
            .AddMvc()
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix);


    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        var supportedCultures = new string[] { "en-GB", "fr-FR" };

        app.UseRequestLocalization();
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{culture=en-gb}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();


        });          
    }
```

You will see here that indeed its setting the culture to France but my dropdown has defaulted back to its default setting? There was no javascript in the Microsoft docs to help this situation at all.

[image]

Comment: In the documentation sample they are using a regular select-element (which has a tag-helper that solves this for you). You on the other hand is implementing a custom select using bootstrap or some other framework so you'll have to handle this yourself. How this has to be done can probably be read in your framework docs instead.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren that worked sorry took a second pair of eyes thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else, Karl was indeed correct if you place the following it appears ms has updated their docs. If you create your dropdown as per below it will work.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options

@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
@inject IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> LocOptions
@{
    var requestCulture = Context.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
    var cultureItems = LocOptions.Value.SupportedUICultures
        .Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.Name, Text = c.DisplayName })
        .ToList();
    var returnUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Context.Request.Path) ? "~/" : $"~{Context.Request.Path.Value}";
}

<div title="@Localizer["Request culture provider:"] @requestCulture?.Provider?.GetType().Name">
    <form id="selectLanguage" asp-controller="Home"
          asp-action="SetLanguage" asp-route-returnUrl="@returnUrl"
          method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <label asp-for="@requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name">@Localizer["Language:"]</label> <select name="culture"
                                                                                                               onchange="this.form.submit();"
                                                                                                               asp-for="@requestCulture.RequestCulture.UICulture.Name" asp-items="cultureItems">
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```